# PHP why can functions reference variables that don't exist yet?

Tags: php, function, if-statement, global-variables

Take a page `<input type="text" name="a">` and `<"input type="submit" name="submit">`.

To avoid "undefined index" and "undefined variable" warnings inserted all over that page I have to not only wrap `if ($a > whatever) { do whatever }` in `if (isset($a))` but even have to wrap `$a = $_POST['a']` in `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`!

But within a function? Don't ever in my life have to type `isset` again. I still apparently have to *call* functions from within an `isset($a)`. But if parts of the function itself depend on a nonexistent `$a`? Those parts just don't run. No errors messing up my whole website. Just a blank space where the function was called.

Why can only functions work this way?